Host Windows, Guest Ubuntu - Set Static IP for Guest
My host machine is a dedicated windows server. I installed Oracle VirtualBox with VM running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
I have internet access using NAT. But the problem is I need the Ubuntu VM to have a static IP (can be the same as the Windows Server).
My end goal is to turn the VM into a self hosted Ubuntu GitHub action runner with a static IP to get through a firewall.
I have spent about 6+ hours trying to get the network connection working with no luck. I switched the connection to bridged, but no matter how I configure it I can't access the internet on the VM.
Not sure if this is relevant, but my host machine's ethernet adapter has 'DHCP Enabled: false'. From my understanding, if I am using a static IP I will not be using DHCP. Any help is appreciated.

Is the Ubuntu VM running desktop edition with a GUI or server without a GUI?  They use different management systems for networking.

In the settings for VirtualBox, you need to set the Network setting to "Bridge". This will allow the VM to get an IP address via DHCP from your router that is in the same subnet as your host. To make it a static IP, have your router assign a static IP to this VM. Alternatively, keep it in "Bridge" mode and set a static IP address in the VM itself that is in the same subnet as your host. But you need to tell us what version and distro of Ubuntu you're using for the VM before advice can be given as to how to set a static IP address in the VM itself.

@ThomasWard It has a GUI

@mpboden I updated the post to include the version. I do not have admin access to the router, FYI. I am willing to try either method. All my work so far has been attempting your second suggestion.

@Uuuuuumm use Network Manager, set the LAN / Ethernet static IP in Network Manager's settings for LAN.  Use Bridged Networking on your VM's settings. Use an IP address that is in your router/firewall's network to set a Static IP within that range

You have to think and treat your host and VM as two different computers. It's perfectly valid to have the host get its IP via DHCP yet have a static IP for the VM.

Additionally, you need to set a static IP on the VM outside the range of IPs the router is serving via DHCP. Without access to the router, I'm not sure how to discover this.

@ThomasWard, & mpboden Thank you for your replies. I just got it working with a bridged connection. I made a guess on an available static IP. (Perhaps this will cause issues down the line). Before I was trying to make the static IP the same as the host. If you want to make answers, I will upvote/accept them.

@mpboden most routers keep an ARP table internally to avoid IP conflicts in DHCP space though.  So yeah they're going to have to guess on the DHCP range or just pick an IP and hope there doesn't happen a conflict.

@Uuuuuumm there you go, enjoy!  Glad we could help you as well!  :D

Firstly treat your VM and your computer as separate entities. On the network you cannot have the same IP or it'll break everything.
Secondly, you have a GUI.  Use Network Manager to edit the LAN settings to set a static IP in the IPv4 tab.  Make sure that tab is a different IP address than your host computer, but in the same subnet.
Thirdly, make sure your VM is in Bridged Adapter mode so it shows independent on your home network.
This will permit your settings to properly work.


NOTE: This does not include the specifics of how to configure the network because OP has already indicated they know where to do that, they just needed some guidance on what to configure where, and how to handle the VM vs. Host settings. This is why this answer does not go into further detail on the configurations.

